# Batch files renaming w/ filename's shift

Tags: command-line, scripts

I have a ton of files named this way: `[name]_[phonenumber]_HH-mm-ss_dd-MM-yyyy.mp3`.
How can I shift `[name]` and `[phonenumber]` to the end of file name, and put the date in the beginning in form of `yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss` so I get `yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss_[name]_[phonenumber]`?

Here is an actual file name: `[Unknown]_[+74999519075]_18-01-36_17-01-2014.mp3`

I've tried `rename`, but due to lack of regexp knowledge I didn't come up with a working solution.

Comment: Can you give us some actual examples?

Comment: Yes, here is an actual file name: **[Unknown]_[+74999519075]_18-01-36_17-01-2014.mp3**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work:

```
for i in *mp3; do rename 's/(.+?)_(.+?)_(.+?)-(.+?)-(.+?)_(.+?)-(.+?)-(.+?).mp3/$8-$7-$6_$3-$4-$5_$1_$2.mp3/' "$i"; done
```

The parentheses capture patterns. The 1st captured match is `$1`, the 2nd `$2` etc. So, the command above:

- will look for everything up to the first `_`
- `.+?` means match the shortest pattern possible because of the `?`,
- then everything up to the 2nd `_` etc.
- and renames accordingly.

I tested it with:

```
$ touch [name]_[phonenumber]_HH-mm-ss_dd-MM-yyyy.mp3
$ ls
[name]_[phonenumber]_HH-mm-ss_dd-MM-yyyy.mp3
$ for i in *mp3; do rename 's/(.+?)_(.+?)_(.+?)-(.+?)-(.+?)_(.+?)-(.+?)-(.+?).mp3/$8-$7-$6_$3-$4-$5_$1_$2.mp3/' "$i"; done
$ ls
yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss_[name]_[phonenumber].mp3
```

Answer (score 7):

Just using your example, if we treat underscore as a reserved delimiter, you can rename them like this:

```
rename 's/^([^_]+)_([^_]+)_([^_]+)_(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)/$6-$5-$4_$3_$1_$2/' *.mp3 -vn
```

The `-vn` on the end means it'll just *tell* you what it would do in the real world. Remove that to make it run.

---

Here's my test harness using your example:

```
$ rename 's/^([^_]+)_([^_]+)_([^_]+)_(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)/$6-$5-$4_$3_$1_$2/' *.mp3 -vn
[Unknown]_[+74999519075]_18-01-36_17-01-2014.mp3 renamed as 2014-01-17_18-01-36_[Unknown]_[+74999519075].mp3
```