# Copying files to directories according the file name

Tags: command-line, bash, filemanager, rename

I have a webdav server containing thousands of files:

```
└── Sync
     ├── 20180719_120823.jpg
     ├── 20180719_120933.jpg
     ├── 20190719_120955.jpg
     ├── 20190719_121023.jpg
     ├── 20190719_121032.jpg
     ├── 20190720_121037.jpg
     ├── 20190721_120823.mp4
     ├── 20190822_220013.jpg
     └── 20190822_230155.mp4
                 "
                 "
```

The first part of file name is YYYYMMDD. I want to use this to copy files to another drive using below structure. Bonus if MM is translated to name of month...:

```
├── 2018
│    └── Jul
│         ├── 20180719_120823.jpg
│         └── 20180719_120933.jpg
└── 2019 
     ├── Jul
     │    ├── 20190719_120955.jpg
     │    ├── 20190719_121023.jpg
     │    ├── 20190719_121032.jpg
     │    ├── 20190720_121037.jpg
     │    └── 20190721_120823.mp4
     └── Aug
          ├── 20190822_220013.jpg
          └── 20190822_230155.mp4
```

I can manually create the year/month structure.
But it would be nice if the directories are created if it doesn't exist.
The script will run once/day and if file already exist, we skip it.

Comment: OK, so what part of this is giving you trouble? What do you have so far? Please show us what you have tried so we don't give you solutions that you know won't work.

Comment: I have been looking at the rename utility, but don't know how to use part of filename to create new path.
Like this post [https://askubuntu.com/questions/483233/change-directory-structure-from-year-month-day-to-year-month-day/483594#483594] and also: [https://askubuntu.com/questions/457705/batch-files-renaming-w-filenames-shift/457710#457710]

Comment: If you can still change that, I would recommend not the `2019/Aug/` structure, but `2019/08/` (or maybe `2019-08/`). That's likely much easier to work with in a variety of situations. It sorts well lexicographically, it's not case sensitive, it's not as much affected by localization. I understand if it's an existing structure you can't change; I figured I'd better share the advice anyway.

Comment: One alternative is `2019/08-Aug/` Then it will be sorted in correct order...

Answer (score 10):

Something like this can be done in Bash:

Where you have:

```
$ tree Sync/
Sync/
├── 20180719_120823.jpg
├── 20190719_120823.jpg
├── 20190719_120920.jpg
├── 20190720_121037.jpg
├── 20190822_120823.jpg
└── 20190822_120823.mp4

1 directory, 6 files
```

Then, you do:

```bash
$ for f in Sync/*
  do
  if [ -f "$f" ]
    then
    n="${f/*\//}" # Get filename
    y="${n:0:4}" # Get Year part
    m="${n:4:2}" # Get Month part
    mn="$(date -d "$m/01/2000" "+%b")" # Translate Month number to name
    mkdir -p Dest/"${y}/${mn}" # Create destination directories if they don't exist
    cp -nv -- "$f" Dest/"${y}/${mn}/"
    fi
  done
'Sync/20180719_120823.jpg' -> 'Dest/2018/Jul/20180719_120823.jpg'
'Sync/20190719_120823.jpg' -> 'Dest/2019/Jul/20190719_120823.jpg'
'Sync/20190719_120920.jpg' -> 'Dest/2019/Jul/20190719_120920.jpg'
'Sync/20190720_121037.jpg' -> 'Dest/2019/Jul/20190720_121037.jpg'
'Sync/20190822_120823.jpg' -> 'Dest/2019/Aug/20190822_120823.jpg'
'Sync/20190822_120823.mp4' -> 'Dest/2019/Aug/20190822_120823.mp4'
```

To get:

```
$ tree Dest/
Dest/
├── 2018
│   └── Jul
│       └── 20180719_120823.jpg
└── 2019
    ├── Aug
    │   ├── 20190822_120823.jpg
    │   └── 20190822_120823.mp4
    └── Jul
        ├── 20190719_120823.jpg
        ├── 20190719_120920.jpg
        └── 20190720_121037.jpg

6 directories, 6 files
```

---

**Notice** that the `date` command used above to translate month numbers to month names will do so according to the default locale (*i.e. language*) on your system, but you can change that to another language/locale (*needs to be already installed on your system*) by temporarily setting the `LC_ALL` environment variable on the same line and directly before the `date` command like for example to translate month numbers to Swedish month names, you'd change the above related line from:

```bash
mn="$(date -d "$m/01/2000" "+%b")" # Translate Month number to name
```

To:

```
mn="$(LC_ALL=sv_SE.utf8 date -d "$m/01/2000" "+%b")" # Translate Month number to Swedish name
```

.. which will for example translate the month number `10` to the Swedish short name `okt`. If you want the full name, you can change `"+%b"` to `"+%B"` which will respectively translate to `oktober`.

Answer (score 10):

Here's one way:

```
declare -A months=( 
 [01]="Jan" 
 [02]="Feb" 
 [03]="Mar" 
 [04]="Apr" 
 [05]="May" 
 [06]="Jun" 
 [07]="Jul" 
 [08]="Aug" 
 [09]="Sep" 
 [10]="Oct" 
 [11]="Nov" 
 [12]="Dec"
) 

for file in Sync/*; do
    year=$(cut -c 1-4 <<<"${file##*/}") 
    month=$(cut -c 5-6 <<<"${file##*/}")
    mkdir -p "$year/${months[$month]}"
    cp -n -- "$file" "$year/${months[$month]}"
 done
```

First we create an associative array linking numbers to month names. Then, for every file in the `Sync` directory, we use `cut` to extract the year and month (see https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html for an explanation of the `${file##*/}` format). Then, `mkdir -p` to create the directory if it doesn't exist, and then we move the file. The `-n` option to `cp` makes sure that existing files are not overwritten (with thanks to @Raffa who added it!).

Answer (score 6):

Thank's for input... this was fun !
I ended up with a combination of both suggestions above.

```
#! /bin/bash

# Declare monts in Swedish
declare -A months=(
 [01]="Januari"
 [02]="Februari"
 [03]="Mars"
 [04]="April"
 [05]="Maj"
 [06]="Juni"
 [07]="Juli"
 [08]="Augusti"
 [09]="September"
 [10]="Oktober"
 [11]="November"
 [12]="December"
)

for f in /mnt/4TB/apa/*
do
  if [ -f "$f" ]; then
   filename="${f##*/}" # Get the base filename

    # pick the first 9 characters
    first_nine="${filename:0:9}"

    # Use regular expression to check if the first nine characters are 8 digits followed by an underscore
    if [[ "$first_nine" =~ ^[0-9]{8}_ ]]; then
           n="${f/*\//}" # Get filename
           y="${n:0:4}" # Get Year part
           m="${n:4:2}" # Get Month part
           mn="${months[$m]}" # Get Month in Swedish
           mkdir -p /mnt/4TB/bepa/"${y}/${mn}" # Create destination directories if they don't exist
           cp -np -- "$f" /mnt/4TB/bepa/"${y}/${mn}/" # Copy file
    fi
  fi
done
```

Comment: A few things to note: 1) Breaking the shebang with space will render the path to the interpreter none-resolvable. 2) `/bin/sh` on Ubuntu is most likely linked to another shell e.g. Dash not Bash and your script needs the latter to run correctly, so use `/bin/bash` instead. 3) If you tell `date` to use Swedish with e.g. `LC_ALL=sv_SE.utf8 date  …`, then it will do so.

Comment: … enough with critique :-) .., You exhibit excellent coding capabilities and perfect parameter quoting  with apparently quick learning gift (*comparing your question to your answer in a short time frame*) which I, personally, find outstanding.

Comment: @Raffa point (1) has been debunked I think - see for example [Is space allowed between #! and /bin/bash in shebang?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/276751/is-space-allowed-between-and-bin-bash-in-shebang)

Comment: Thank you @Raffa.. I don´t take it as critique. I'm learning from it.
I have been coding when I was younger, but this is actuallly my first bash script ever. Picking up pieces from here and there and putting it together. Great fun !

Comment: @steeldriver I’m glad it’s been debunked … That and `/bin/sh` were holding my upvote to this answer and I wanted to :-) … Now **+1**